# jQuery on click not working after DOM was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I have setup my HTML in razor like following:

```
  @if (ViewBag.Added != null)
                            {
                                if (ViewBag.Added == false)
                                {                        
                                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="wholeBtn">

                                     <a class="btn btn-app btnWatchList" style="min-width:100%;margin:0;height:67px">
                                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Add to Watchlist
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                                }
                                else if (ViewBag.Added)
                                {
                                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="addedToWatchList" style="padding:10px 0">
                                        <h4 style="text-align:center;margin-top:20px"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color:darkseagreen;font-size:25px"></i> Watching</h4>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="wholeBtn">

                                    <a class="btn btn-app btnWatchList" style="min-width:175px;margin:0;height:67px">
                                        <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Add to Watchlist
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
```

The onclick button looks like this:

```
$(".btnSaveWatchlist").on("click", function (event) {
       $.post("/User/SaveWatchList", { comment: $('#TextArea1').val(), rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(), competitor: $('.txtSearch').val() }, $(this).prop('disabled', true))
                             .done(function (data) {
                                 if (data == "AllFieldsRequired") {
                                     ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
                                     return;
                                 }
                                 else {
                                     $('.hideit').hide();
                                     $('.canvas').show();
                                     AnimateGreenCheck();
                                     setTimeout(function () {
                                         var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#addedToWatchList').html();
                                         $('#wholeBtn').html(result);
                                         var l = document.getElementById('cancelButton');
                                         l.click();
                                     },
                                   3000);

                                     setTimeout(function () {
                                         ResetWatchListField();
                                     },
                                  4500);
                                 }
                             });
});
```

So initially this button "Add to watchlist" isn't present in DOM. It is loaded into the DOM after an search is performed on website.

Once that is done, onclick event works very fine. When post is done, I hide the button and update the DOM to show user that he added this user to watchlist.

Performing the search now again on different user that wasnt added to watchlist, and the button "Add to watchlist" with class "btnSaveWatchlist" is again loaded into the DOM.

But this time it is completely unresponsive... I checked whether the action in controller gets initiated, it doesn't ... The button seems like it's "Frozen"...

Any ideas what could it be guys?

P.S. All this is done without refreshing the page at all. I don't want to refresh the page at all for end user...

Edit here is the btnSaveWatchList button with the class:

```
  <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel" id="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
    <button class="remodal-confirm btnSaveWatchlist">Save</button>
```

Comment: Where is the class btnSaveWatchlist in your HTML?

Comment: @TimGrant I have shown the HTML markup above...

Comment: ...which does not appear to have the btnSaveWatchlist class.

Comment: That's odd ,my bad.. I'll add it :)

Comment: @TimGrant Added the HTML for the button

Comment: I don't want to be the one who points out the obvious but there's a few reasons why this could break: 1 ) You are rendering the html with jquery *after setting the binding*. In this case, you would have to re-set the binding like `element.off('click'); element.on('click', myfunction()}`. Another simple reason is invalid html.

Comment: @Babydead what is off method here used for ?

Comment: @User987 to remove the old bindings (otherwise it stacks up and gets RAM hungry, or maybe even trigger multiple times). Either way, you will need to set the bindings **after** you render html in jquery. The nicest way to do this is to create a function that binds it and call to said function like `element.html(myhtml).promise().done(setbindings);`

Comment: @Babydead how would this look like in my example? Could you reply with answer so that I can accept it if it works ? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas what could it be guys?

yeah, the difference between the markup (basically a plain string) and the Document Object Model. You attach event-listener to particular DOM-nodes, but when loading new markup, this node is disposed, and a new one is created from the markup you've provided.

And the event listener is also gone with the old node.

```
//listen for every 'click' event on an '.btnSaveWatchlist' that bubbles up to the `document.body`
$(document.body).on("click", ".btnSaveWatchlist", function (event) {
    //don't inline such stuff, it's completely unreadable
    var postData = { 
        comment: $('#TextArea1').val(), 
        rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(), 
        competitor: $('.txtSearch').val() 
    };

    //don't know why you put this into the $.post() call.
    //this line returns $(this), but the arguments for $.post() 
    //are url, data, successHandler and dataType.
    //and $(this) is neither a successHandler, nor a dataType
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    $.post("/User/SaveWatchList", postData)
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response == "AllFieldsRequired") {
                ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
                return;
            } else {
                $('.hideit').hide();
                $('.canvas').show();

                AnimateGreenCheck();

                setTimeout(function() {
                    //you don't need to manually parse the response
                    var result = $('#addedToWatchList', response)
                        .html();

                    $('#wholeBtn').html( result );

                    //don't try to fire a click-event by code. 
                    //Better call the function that gets executed if this event happened

                    //since chances are good, that you used jQuery to register this click-listener
                    //triggering the click-event will probably call it.
                    //this is more reliable than relying on the click-function of a dom-node.
                    $('#cancelButton').click();
                }, 3000);

                //a function that just forwards the call to another function is useless
                //just pass the function you want to call.
                setTimeout(ResetWatchListField, 4500);
             }
        });
});
```

Comment: it says "body is not defined" ?

Comment: @User987 sry, fixed that. It should have been either `document.body` or `"body"`

Comment: thanks for that, still it works only in first event click, on 2nd event click the button is still frozen :/

Answer (score 3):

Your code is quite unclear to me at this time, so I'm not 100% sure this will solve the issue, but here's my go at it:

You are probably binding an element that you are rendering with jquery at a later time.

There are 2 ways to solve this. The easiest one (to me) is to use a parent-child style binding.
This means you put the binding on the parent, and `jQuery` checks whether or not the child is clicked after the fact. This actually works with dynamic content (html that was loaded in through ajax or whatever)

**Example:**

```
var $parent = $('#parent'); //the element you append your html to

$parent.on('click', '.btnSaveWatchlist', function(){
  //Do whatever you want here
  //The binding will hold as long as the parent doesn't get replaced.
});
```

Or, there's the other way; making your function call re-set the binding every time you render the html (a tad less efficient)

**Example:**

Please note my comments here. I'm missing a lot of info so I put some "questions" in there.

```
function setBinding(){

  $(".btnSaveWatchlist").off('click');
  $(".btnSaveWatchlist").on("click", function (event) {
       $.post("/User/SaveWatchList", { comment: $('#TextArea1').val(), rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(), competitor: $('.txtSearch').val() }, $(this).prop('disabled', true))
         .done(function (data) {
           if (data == "AllFieldsRequired") {
             ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
             return; //this is not valid. make it true or false.
           }
           else {
             $('.hideit').hide();
             $('.canvas').show();
             AnimateGreenCheck();

             setTimeout(function () {
               var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#addedToWatchList').html();
               $('#wholeBtn').html(result);
               var l = document.getElementById('cancelButton');

               //Why do you trigger the cancel button here? Doesn't this always cause it to cancel right away?
               l.click();
             },3000);

              setTimeout(function () {
                 ResetWatchListField();
                 //is this where you reset the html?
                 //in that case:
                 setBinding();
              }, 4500);
            }
        });
  });
}
```

You have to call `setBinding()` for a first time somewhere (like on `document.ready?`), or it won't work.

Note that you should call the `setBinding()` function after you render the button you need.

Somewhere, outside of the code you're showing in your question, you render this button. Whether it's true `append()` or `html()`, I don't know, but wherever you render this button, add this after the `html()`: `element.html(myhtml).promise().done(setBinding);`

Comment: with 2nd method event doesn't triggers at all

Comment: @User987 because I'm missing necessary information to make that one work. Though I would recommend the first method, since it's a lot easier. Anyway, updated my answer a bit.

Comment: very interesting, I've called function bindButton(); right after document.ready, it triggers first time, 2nd time it doesnt

Comment: babydead, where would I actually call event from method 1 ? Within the .done() from first event? o.O

Comment: @User987 sorry, got a bit busy. With method one, you don't neeed to call any event at all. Just replace your current binding with the binding method of method 1. With method 2, yes, you'd need to call it in the `.done()` from the first event that generates the button.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you cerate a function with binding action.

```
function bindButton() {
    $(".btnSaveWatchlist").click(function () {
        $.post("/User/SaveWatchList", { comment: $('#TextArea1').val(), rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(), competitor: $('.txtSearch').val() }, $(this).prop('disabled', true))
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data == "AllFieldsRequired") {
                    ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    $('.hideit').hide();
                    $('.canvas').show();
                    AnimateGreenCheck();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#addedToWatchList').html();
                        $('#wholeBtn').html(result);
                        var l = document.getElementById('cancelButton');
                        l.click();
                        bindButton();
                    },
                        3000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        ResetWatchListField();
                        bindButton();
                    },
                        4500);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

In your document ready, just call bindButton function. Then, after every call, you will have your button binded again, because your are cleaning the content of the div.

Comment: Federico, by doing this I get:Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in my console...

Comment: @User987 that generally means there's an infinite loop / nesting in your code somewhere.

Comment: @Babydead yes the AnimateGreenCheck button calls for loop =(

Comment: You are right. I have mistaken. You have to add the click handler in the function, not the post itself. Also, I would suggest to extract your code in multiple methods, so it's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @User987 can you post the given error in the developer console? I have updated the code. Could you try now?

Comment: @FedericoAlecci yes still same, nothing happens , no errors in console still

Comment: @User987 chrome actually hides quite a few errors in the console these days to stop your JS from breaking. Try making sure all the elements are actually found and check the `XHR` tab in your `network` tab. (also, disable caching there if you haven't yet, it helps!)

Comment: @User987 and do not forget to clean the cache of chrome (Ctrl + F5 in Windows)